# How can I access real-time health data from Zepp OS (Xiaomi/Amazfit)? Do I need any permission for this? Need some working samples

Tags: fetch, real-time-data, sony-smartwatch, zeppos

I need to fetch realtime health related data from zepp os based smart watches to build a ML model. How can I do this. Need some working samples

I explored theit documentation but not getting the exact working procedure .